# Attempting to email ing Reporting Services, error due to OAuth changes?

Tags: sql-server, email, reporting-services, oauth, report

We are on Windows Server 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2016 using a smtp office 365 server for our email in Reporting Services. The service has stopped working using Username and password (Basic) because, we believe, it now requires Oauth. There is no clear option for that in Reporting Services.  The error in the reporting logs is below.

Has anyone else had to deal with this issue with Reporting Services mailing a report? Is there a solution for this?

---

> ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException:
> Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data
> from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.    at
> System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine)    at
> System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader
> caller, Boolean oneLine)    at
> System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader
> caller)    at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn,
> String& response)    at
> System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command,
> MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)    at
> System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
> MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean
> allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)    at
> System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

---

EDIT: Apologies, apparently I was sent the wrong error that was happening.

Comment: The message would appear to just be related to a malformed email address `The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.`

Comment: Check the sender and recipient email addresses to ensure that they follow the `localpart@remote.server.domain` format and do not contain any whitespace characters or other information. e.g.: `"John Smith" <jsmith@gmail.com>` would be invalid, `jsmith@gmail.com` would be valid.